# gITF 2.0 model imported from Blender into Godot engine is broken

Tags: 3d, blender, godot4

I'm trying to import simple 3d model from Blender into Godot engine. But imported model is missing some faces for unknown reason.

How model is viewed in Blender
[image: How model is viewed in Blender]

How model is viewed in Godot engine
[image: How model is viewed in Godot engine]

Video, demonstrating broken model: https://www.veed.io/view/277419c3-5cd0-4b03-b9ce-2174cb777cdf?panel=share

Model file: https://file.io/JL0FHQHnvayl

Blender version: 3.0.1

Godot Engine version: v4.1.2.stable.mono.official [399c9dc39]

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Tried with Blender 3.6.5 - same thing.

UPD2: Same thing for model in DAE(Collada) and OBJ(Wavefront) formats.

UPD3:
Same when importing .blend file
[image]

Comment: The model has incorrect normals. You could workaround by using a material without face culling. However this is a modelling problem, try https://blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: Theraot thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. I've found problematic area with "Select All By Trait" -> "Non Manifold". And fixed it by "Remesh" modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to Theraot comment.

- Search problematic vertices by "Select" -> "Select All By Trait" -> "Non Manifold"
- Split area, containing problematic vertices into an object
- Apply "Remesh" filter to it
- Optionally apply "Decimate" filter.
- Merge remeshed object back to main object